# Load drawables in GridView with "Bitmapfun project" from Android Developer

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview

I have this project in my Eclipse: [PROJECT](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

and I want to load drawables from my resources folders and not from Internet.

This project have the method I need for load images Asyncrounsly and cache and diskcache. I need all this methods for my project and I don't know how to do it for load drawables and not Internet Images.

If anyone can help me downloading the project called BitmapFun will help me a lot.

I paste here some interesting code for easy help:

```
mImageFetcher.loadImage(Images.imageThumbUrls[position - mNumColumns], imageView);
```

**loadImge method:**

```
/**
 * Load an image specified by the data parameter into an ImageView (override
 * {@link ImageWorker#processBitmap(Object)} to define the processing logic). A memory and
 * disk cache will be used if an {@link ImageCache} has been added using
 * {@link ImageWorker#addImageCache(FragmentManager, ImageCache.ImageCacheParams)}. If the
 * image is found in the memory cache, it is set immediately, otherwise an {@link AsyncTask}
 * will be created to asynchronously load the bitmap.
 *
 * @param data The URL of the image to download.
 * @param imageView The ImageView to bind the downloaded image to.
 */
public void loadImage(Object data, ImageView imageView) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }

    BitmapDrawable value = null;

    if (mImageCache != null) {
        value = mImageCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(String.valueOf(data));
    }

    if (value != null) {
        // Bitmap found in memory cache
        imageView.setImageDrawable(value);
    } else if (cancelPotentialWork(data, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(mResources, mLoadingBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);

        // NOTE: This uses a custom version of AsyncTask that has been pulled from the
        // framework and slightly modified. Refer to the docs at the top of the class
        // for more info on what was changed.
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.DUAL_THREAD_EXECUTOR, data);
    }
}
```

**BitmapWorkerTask method:**

```
/**
 * The actual AsyncTask that will asynchronously process the image.
 */
private class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, BitmapDrawable> {
    private Object data;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    /**
     * Background processing.
     */
    @Override
    protected BitmapDrawable doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground - starting work");
        }

        data = params[0];
        final String dataString = String.valueOf(data);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        BitmapDrawable drawable = null;

        // Wait here if work is paused and the task is not cancelled
        synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
            while (mPauseWork && !isCancelled()) {
                try {
                    mPauseWorkLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        // If the image cache is available and this task has not been cancelled by another
        // thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still bound back
        // to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set then try and fetch the bitmap from
        // the cache
        if (mImageCache != null && !isCancelled() && getAttachedImageView() != null
                && !mExitTasksEarly) {
            bitmap = mImageCache.getBitmapFromDiskCache(dataString);
        }

        // If the bitmap was not found in the cache and this task has not been cancelled by
        // another thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still
        // bound back to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set, then call the main
        // process method (as implemented by a subclass)
        if (bitmap == null && !isCancelled() && getAttachedImageView() != null
                && !mExitTasksEarly) {
            bitmap = processBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        // If the bitmap was processed and the image cache is available, then add the processed
        // bitmap to the cache for future use. Note we don't check if the task was cancelled
        // here, if it was, and the thread is still running, we may as well add the processed
        // bitmap to our cache as it might be used again in the future
        if (bitmap != null) {
            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                // Running on Honeycomb or newer, so wrap in a standard BitmapDrawable
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
            } else {
                // Running on Gingerbread or older, so wrap in a RecyclingBitmapDrawable
                // which will recycle automagically
                drawable = new RecyclingBitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
            }

            if (mImageCache != null) {
                mImageCache.addBitmapToCache(dataString, drawable);
            }
        }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground - finished work");
        }

        return drawable;
    }

    /**
     * Once the image is processed, associates it to the imageView
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BitmapDrawable value) {
        // if cancel was called on this task or the "exit early" flag is set then we're done
        if (isCancelled() || mExitTasksEarly) {
            value = null;
        }

        final ImageView imageView = getAttachedImageView();
        if (value != null && imageView != null) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute - setting bitmap");
            }
            setImageDrawable(imageView, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(BitmapDrawable value) {
        super.onCancelled(value);
        synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
            mPauseWorkLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ImageView associated with this task as long as the ImageView's task still
     * points to this task as well. Returns null otherwise.
     */
    private ImageView getAttachedImageView() {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (this == bitmapWorkerTask) {
            return imageView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Anyone can say me if with this project I can load images from drawables folder and not from Interet?

Thanks in advance!!!

**Edit:**
I know that this code works correctly with Images from Internet and it's that I want but with folder drawables images.
So, I tried to change code like:

```
mImageFetcher.loadImage(***R.drawables.image233***, imageView);
```

but it not work because give a error because isn't a Internet image.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You want to know how to load bitmap from resources? Or do you want to know if above code fetches from net or resources?

Comment: I want to use this code for load images from resources because I was try to do it and it only allow to load internet images. I want to know if this code can load resources images too and how to do it...

Comment: You're spamming StackOverflow with the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load drawables in GridView with “Bitmapfun project” from Android Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899767/load-drawables-in-gridview-with-bitmapfun-project-from-android-developer)

Comment: Because I'm waiting for answer more then 15 days... What I need to do if no one answer me... :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how you can run this project on Eclipse ADT! Follow this steps...

1 - Import project in eclipse adt
2 - copy all folders that initiate "com" in the java folders to the src Android project
3 - Note that your project have some errors, you need to change the android project build target, to make this, you have to right click on android -> Properties -> Android -> select Android 4.4.2 -> Apply -> Ok
4 - Add external jar that located in adt-bundle-... -> sdk -> extras -> android -> support -> v4 -> android-support-v4. To do this, right click on android project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars.
5 - clean project
6 - run it.

Hope I have helped.

Ps:. The structure of the project was different because it was made by Studio IDE